# Filter and logical operators

Tags: google-sheets, logical-operators

EZ stuff but after an hour.. `=filter(May15!A:S , May15!E:E="Authorization")` is yielding a rich populated sheet.  However I can't get OR working!  Despite it working elsewhere in the sheet.  I'd like other possibilities via the same filter.  I tried several including the OR this way

```
 =filter(May15!A:S , OR(May15!E:E="Authorization" , May15!E:E="bigwhale", May15!E:E="hi"))
```

.. to no avail.  Any help appreciated.  Also, I read somewhere the OR could be accessed using a "+" and that sounded like a neat method.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use RegEx:

```
=filter(H:H , REGEXMATCH(E:E,JOIN("|",A1:A3)))
```

put in `A1:A3`:

```
Authorization
bigwhale
hi
```

This trick is useful when you need to add conditions, just paste one more value in cell `A4` and use range `A1:A4`

---

Another way is to use plus sign:

```
=FILTER(H:H,(E:E="Authorization")+(E:E="bigwhale")+(E:E="hi"))
```

Comment: Yes the plus sign! Thank you Max!!  A big help.  I played w RegExMatch a bit but its case sensitive and that moved me to the SEARCH() command in a different part of the sheet.

Comment: Oh yeah!  I had multiple forms of same data (hI vs HI etc) and with commas too.  I found the `=REGEXMATCH(E:E,"(?i)test")` to solve the case insensitivity problem, and I appreciate the alternate (and probably better) method.  However.. varying punctionation among the same data is now my problem.  I've seen suggestions for normalizing the data using UPPER() and some ruby commands, but I'm wondering if a variant of `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1:A10, B1)` is possible.. as written, it is not, and JOIN()  doesn't work with search()

Comment: Please provide sample file and show example of varying punctionation. The usage of different formulas depends on specific case.